# Slidify Example Page Doesn't Work

Tags: html, r, slidify

When I open [this slidify presentation](http://ramnathv.github.io/slidifyExamples/examples/io2012/#1) all I got is the first slide. It doesn't change and I can't do anything about it. Same thing happens when I try the package example on my computer.

It looks more like a problem with my browser instead of R or the package.

Comment: Did you use the right arrow button?  Can you open: http://ramnathv.github.io/slidifyExamples/examples/io2012/#2?  Can you open it in another browser?  If not I'd ask Ramnath at the GitHub page's issues: https://github.com/ramnathv/slidify/issues?state=open

Comment: Did you try what Tyler suggested. You can navigate the slides using the arrow keys.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Arrow keys work well.

Comment: Btw thanks for the great work Ramnath.

Comment: Great. If either you or @TylerRinker can write this up as an answer, it can be accepted and closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arrow keys flip the slides. Case closed.